# CakePHP: With or without Auth Component?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently using this for my admin panel: **[Admin Section](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_1_3_3_admin_section_template_files/)**

**I have a simple question:** Do I have to use Auth Component or is this enough secure way to use for admin section?

If you recommend Auth Component, are there any decent tutorials to begin with? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is hard to answer since the site you link to does not really describe what it does, you'd have to download the zip file and examine the code, something I'm honestly not willing to do just to answer this question...

Comment: There's a version for version 1.2: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated Any opinions, why this wouldn't be as secure as Auth Component?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to learn more about Auth later. But right now I think I'll keep using James Fairhurst's solution.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial you posted is tested on CakePHP 1.3.3 and your question is tagged with CakePHP 2.0 . If you are using 2.0 > using Auth will most likely prevent the problem of backward incompatibility and if there are changes to Auth then the CakePHP authors will advise you in a migration guide.

Im sorry I dont know of a good tutorial but there is the manual and a good google should bring some up.

Comment: I'm using 2.0. There's a version for version 1.2: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated Any opinions, why this wouldn't be as secure as Auth Component?

Comment: I was more coming from the approach of problem you could have supporting a snippet from a previous version of the framework. If you extend your app you will want to use the Auth component for its simplicity.  Also if you intend to use CakePhp you will have to learn Auth eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Auth Component... Here is a great Auth CakePHP 2.0 tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM